# How using spring-boot-starter-jpa in custom spring-boot-starter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-jpa

I have my custom starter. Inside it, I define a repository. How should I define it in the configuration?  This is how I did the usual bean before.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(HelloWorldController.class)
public HelloWorldController helloWorldController() {
    return new HelloWorldController();
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

And configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DomainConfiguration {
}
```

If you use this starter, context will not see the repository bean. Because I did not declare it in the configuration.I don't know how to declare it.

Comment: Which version of Spring-Boot do you use? You add in some class the packageToScan?

Comment: I used 2.4.0 version. Yes, I tryied add annotation packageToScan it is not help me.The context of the application that used the custom starter did not find the repository, I think this is because it was just not defined in the configuration of the custom starter.

Comment: Thank you I found the problem. I forgot to add an annotation @EntityScan

Comment: Write the answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration class, you must use the @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan annotations, indicating the package in which the Repositories and Entity classes are located

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.my.app.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.my.app.entity"})
public class DomainConfiguration  {
}
```